# Dropdown menu dissapearing on touch event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a legacy website which has a lot of issues, but one of them is really irritating and confusing. It has a dropdown menu within it which is simply toggling using jquery conditionals.

The problem is - when I open it on iPhone/Android and try to scroll down to see the rest of the menu items, the menu dissapears.

Here is the script that loads it:

```
/* MOBILE COLLAPSE MENU */
;(function ($) {
  $.fn.collapsable = function (options) {
  // iterate and reformat each matched element
  return this.each(function () {
  // cache this:
  var obj = $(this)
  var tree = obj.next('.mobile_navigation')
  obj.click(function () {
    if (obj.is(':visible')) {tree.toggle();}
  })
  $(window).resize(function () {
    if ($(window).width() <= 480) {tree.attr('style', '');}
  })
 })
 }
 })(jQuery)
```

How can I fix this? I presume it has something to do with the $(window).resize function since it is loading a smaller viewport, but I dont know what to do about it.

Comment: You can remove then onClick event when you are in mobile device and add a close button.

Comment: Have you tried to comment the resize part? I think this is where your problem come from, and maybe you don't need it anymore, if you want to have the same behaviour on desktop and on mobile

Comment: Commeting out the resize part did it. I was trying to modify it by my taste but didn't tried commenting it out... Thanks , that did it, for now.

Answer (score 0):

Please double check You are importing `jquery` library import twice..

or

Try this one

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){
         $("p").slideToggle();
     });
   });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<button>Toggle slideUp() and slideDown()</button>
</div>

<p><a href="#">Link 1</a></p>
<p><a href="#">Link 1</a></p>
<p><a href="#">Link 1</a></p>
<p><a href="#">Link 1</a></p>

</body>
</html>
```